# MySQL SELECT (many times) or SELECT one time and then use array as variable

Tags: php, mysql

For example MySQL table for invoices (date, amount, buyer name, etc).

User want to select (display/echo) invoices issued during one particular month (for, example, April).

Then user decides that need to display invoices issued during April and to one particular buyer.

I suppose there are 2 options:

1) on each request do MySQL SELECT and fetch required data, or

2) only one MySQL SELECT and fetch; create an array with fetched results; then use/process array

Question is what option would be better for performance? Many MySQL SELECT uses server resources; but on the other hand to keep in memory an array also uses resources. Which option uses less resources?

Comment: You have correctly identified the pros and cons of each approach.  Which is "best" will depend (at very least) on the resources you have available and the volumes of data involved.  Why don't you benchmark both approaches and decide for yourself which is best in your case?

Comment: For #2, where do you plan to store the retrieved data between requests? HTTP is stateless...

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario ... yes, seems I have not thought enough. I thought to use foreach, to create array as variable; Yes, on next click the created variable "disappears" or need to use sessions. OK, thanks for advices. Now is clear that more reasonably to do SELECT on each request.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario I suppose to keep variable, also may use ajax (without page reload). But these are only thoughts regarding how to keep variable....

Comment: AJAX works on top of HTTP. Your PHP script runs, sends output and dies forever, no matter how you invoke it. It's not like desktop apps that keep running for hours.

Comment: Ah, then only possible way seems sessions. Need to use mysql select on each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use the database to get the data.  Try to get the smallest amount you can, grouping by & sum/count on the database.  Use LIMIT etc. for paging.  That way you don't have to have a large array.

If you are processing large sets then fetch them in chunks rather than a row.  Sorry - not PHP expert so can't be sure of the exact term for PHP but I think mysql_fetch_assoc is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I depends how much data you have to get from the database for all the invoices of the month. But I would generally use a MySQL query filtering the results. Mysql queries are much quicker and better optimized when filtering results than doing it on php.